# Ubuntu 20.04, Django, nginx file permission error 403 -no solution in stackoverflow as of now works

Tags: django, python-2.7, nginx, ubuntu-20.04

I have deplloyed Django 1.8 application on ubuntu server with gunicorn

```
Ubuntu 20.04
Django 1.8
nginx 1.18.0 
Python 2.7
```

The media files are having following permissions

```
# ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 18  2021 media
```

Error message I get is

```
2022/01/11 05:26:30 [error] 4094535#4094535: *152 open() "<full path to media>/media/cache/b3/de/b3def88cd24c122f0e1dcaf96e021ec2.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.68.127.176, server: server.com, request: "GET /media/cache/b3/de/b3def88cd24c122f0e1dcaf96e021ec2.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "www.server.com", referrer: "http://www.server.com/"
```

the permissions for files are

```
media# ls -l cache/b3/de/b3def88cd24c122f0e1dcaf96e021ec2.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 24008 Jul 22 23:46 cache/b3/de/b3def88cd24c122f0e1dcaf96e021ec2.jpg
```

nginx config is

```
server {
    server_name server.com www.server.com 192.175.118.100;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/server_error_log error;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    client_max_body_size 250M;
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /home/server/static/;
    }
    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/server/media/media;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/server_gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        #proxy_set_header X-SSL-Protocol $ssl_protocol;
    }

    listen 80;

}
```

We are unable to upload files due to permission error

### UPDATE

The static files works, not media files

Comment: root /home/server/static     , no last / needed in case of root

Comment: The static files works, but error in media files.

Comment: root /home/server/media/media;  might work

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/403-forbidden-for-big-media-files-nginx

Comment: Thank You for the comments, neither of them worked :(